# Use bash script $1 argument in awk command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to create a bash script that takes an argument and using `awk` to print if

it's a orphan process :

```
#find_orphan.sh :

ps -elf | awk '/$1/&&!/awk/ {if ($5 == 1){print $15}}'
```

Unfortunately I'm having problems in order to render the $1 as a bash argument..

if I run this without using $1 my program will work :

```
ps -elf | awk '/some_program/&&!/awk/ {if ($5 == 1){print $15}}'
```

I really need to be able to specify the awk search pattern in the bash script argument.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables are extended only inside double quotes (or no quotes at all) , not single quotes.
You could try

```
ps -elf | awk '/'$1'/&&!/awk/ {if ($5 == 1){print $15}}'
```

For awk I think anubhavas solution is better, but this also works in similar situations with other tools.

Comment: It might be better to use double quotes to avoid wordsplitting on expansion, which could confuse awk (and the user) even more. `awk "/$1/&&!/awk/"'&&$5==1{ print $15 }'`. Note the quote switch from `"` to `'`.

Comment: Probably, I mainly wanted to point out the different behaviour of single and double quotes regarding variable expansion.

Comment: No. Never do this, nor do the nonsense with double quotes suggested in a comment. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for the real way to pass the value of shell variables to awk scripts.

Answer (score 7):

Use `awk -v var=val` to pass a command line value to awk and use `$0 ~ val` syntax to compare it using regex:

```
ps -elf | awk -v arg="$1" '$0 ~ arg && !/awk/ && $5 == 1{print $15}'
```

**Without regex:**

```
ps -elf | awk -v arg="$1" 'index($0, arg) && !/awk/ && $5 == 1{print $15}'
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm aware that this doesn't address the question in the title; it is a solution to the actual problem presented in the text. The question about awk is answered below.*

It's rarely necessary to parse `ps` output, since you can ask `ps` to produce whatever fields you desire. Also, you'll find that `pgrep` is easier to use and more reliable than grepping `ps` for a process name. `pgrep` is installed by default on many Linux distros; if it isn't installed on yours, look at the [procps-ng homepage](https://gitorious.org/procps) for downloads.

`pgrep` can directly search for processes with a particular parent pid:

```
pgrep -P 1 "$1"
```

That will print out a list of process numbers (pids); you can get it to produce process names as well with the `-l` option:

```
pgrep -l -P 1 "$1"
```

If you want the full command-line, you should pass the pids into `ps` and tell it to just produce the `cmd`:

```
pgrep -P 1 "$1" | xargs ps -ocmd=
```

Or, if you prefer, the PID and the command line:

```
pgrep -P 1 "$1" | xargs ps -opid=,cmd=
```

(Leave out the `=` if you like to see column headers.)

---

The best way to pass a command-line parameter into an `awk` script is to set a variable on the command-line. There are two ways to do this:

```
awk -v arg="$1" 'program' "filename"...

awk 'program' arg="$1" "filename"...
```

The difference between the two is that the first form makes `arg` available in `BEGIN` blocks, whereas the second form is interpreted just before `awk` opens the file, so it is not available in `BEGIN` blocks but can be redefined different for subsequent files:

```
awk 'program' arg="value for file1" file1 arg="value for file2" file2
```